# How to programmatically modify security rules in Firebase?

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

The examples in the firebase documents assume manual update of firebase security rules. How can security rules be modified programmatically to support real-world collaborative applications? In the use case that I am considering, the requirement is for a user to be able to invite other users to collaborate/share selected data and to be able to grant/revoke access to the collaborators. How can this be accomplished with firebase?

Answer (score 11):

You actually shouldn't programmatically change your security rules. You should think of them as **code** and only change them at deploy time.

If what you're trying to do is change what users are actually allowed to do, you should do this by writing security rules that depend on data in your Firebase.

For example, lets say you wanted to restrict access to a piece of data to only users in a specific group. Rather than modifying the security rules everytime the group membership changed, you would simply store the group in Firebase and have your security rules check to see if the current user is in that group before allowing access.

```
".read" : "root.child('groups').child($groupID).child(auth.userid).exists()"
```

That way, anytime group membership changes, users will automatically be granted access to the data they should be allowed to see.

For a more complex example of security rules, take a look at the rules.json file in [Firefeed](https://github.com/firebase/firefeed).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Using groups to handle dynamically updated user's makes sense. But how would dynamically added datasets be handled? For example, a user can create a project under /users/userid/projects/projectid and then want to grant read access for that specific project to a group of collaborators. How would that be accomplished with Firebase?

Comment: The group setup was just an example. You don't need to have groups -- you can have it depend on any data you like. For instance the dataset itself could have a "readable" flag, that if set to true allows anyone to read it. Or, it could have a "readable" list of users allowed to use it. Etc...

Comment: @AndrewLee, I have a more complex case: I'm creating rooms (branches) dynamically and I want to limit every room to only X specific collaborators, blocking everybody else from writing there. How can I specify these access rights upon room creation? Note that there could be millions of different rooms.

Comment: This is awesome, i did'nt found this in their doc.
Thanks a alot :)

Answer (score 0):

> But how would dynamically added datasets be handled?

You would do this by using the child `$` node. It looks something like this:

Here is my database

```
users
- userIDHere
  - name: John Doe
  - whatever: who knows
```

And you would set rules on each user by doing this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        // whatever rules you want here, and you can reference $user to get the user's id.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this is what you were asking, and hope this helps!