# Group-based permissions on Firebase

Tags: firebase, permissions, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to give permissions to users based on their usergroups.

Simply checking if a user is a member of that group wouldn't work though, as I want to be able to dynamically create usergroups and set their permissions (without having to change the Firebase Rules).

That's how my data is structured:

```
users: {
  user_1: {
    name: "John Smith",
    creation_date: "1234567890000"
    usergroups: {
      usergroup_1: true,
      usergroup_4: true
    }
  }
  ...
}
usergroups: {
  usergroup_1: {
    name: "admin",
    creation_date: "1234567890000"
    permissions: {
      manage_users: true,
      manage_chat: true,
      manage_calendar: true,
      ...
    }
  }
  usergroup_2: {
    name: "moderator",
    creation_date: "1234567890000"
    permissions: {
      manage_chat: true
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that users may have more than one usergroup, each with a different set of permissions (might be the same).

An example: users will only be able to manage the chat if they are in at least one usergroup that allows them to do so.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this? Maybe by structuring the data on a different way?

Comment: Basing on your scenario, there's a part where you're attempting to change the Firebase Security Rules dynamically, which is [not advised](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591037/4625829).

Comment: Are you sure this would require dynamic rules AL? Because I have the feeling it could all be captured with `$` variables. @atcastroviejo: did you try anything already? You're more likely to get help if you show what you've already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the response. I haven't included any attempts because I couldn't come up with a possible solution. I have thought about $variables but I'm not sure if they would help in that case scenario, unless it possible to access $variables from another path (loop thought all the users usergroups and check if a certain permission exists/is set to true)?

Comment: Looping is not possible. Ah, maybe that's what AL meant.